# two disjoint subset of real number that has the same bounds?

Tags: real-analysis

Find two subset $A$ and $B$ of the real line that A ∩ B is null but they have the same least upper bound and greatest lower bound.
I don't know where to start on this question

Comment: There are **many** different ways you can approach this problem.  Be creative!  While there are wrong answers, there are many totally different correct answers that have little to nothing to do with eachother.  If you really have no ideas, then perhaps think of the following.  Do you know that the set of rational numbers is disjoint from the set of irrational numbers?  Maybe try to use that to your advantage.

Comment: When you encounter a mysterious math problem, explore! Pick your favorite numbers for the greatest lower bound and the least upper bound. Write down one set with those two numbers as *its* greatest lower bound and least upper bound. Write down a different one. Write down more and more of them, tinker with them. Use the "rational/irrational" idea of the other comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A = (0,1), B = \{0,1\}$. Then $A \cap B = \emptyset$, and they have the same l.u.b and g.l.b which are $1,0$ respectively.